# React link's onClick event state change is not happening

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have used react links with mui and I am trying to highlight the active link in header. My attempt is as below.

```
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

const [active, setActive] = useState(0); 
<Link 
   {...{color: "inherit",component: RouterLink, onClick: (()=>setActive(1)),
        style: { textDecoration: active === 1 ? "underline" : "none"},
        to: "abc"}}>
   Abc
</Link>
```

Here when I clicked `abc` for the first time state is not changing. So link is not get underlined. But once I click again state get changed and link gets underlined. So how can I get it underlined even for the first click?

Comment: Please show `setActive` function.

Comment: @m-s7 `const [active, setActive] = useState(0);`

Comment: There's not enough code and detail provided here to really say why a link isn't being marked active. Are you *not* using a `NavLink` component that has this active state built in? Can you edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: FWIW I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-links-onclick-event-state-change-is-not-happening-e796dn). The state updates and the links become "active" upon the first click. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? Feel free to fork from my sandbox.